# Subir solo 1 archivo y multiplicarlo

Tags: php, foreach

Necesito subir varios archivos a partir de 1 solo:

```
foreach($_POST['listas'] as $lista):
  $ext         = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $file_name   = 'EOC_'.$lista.'_'.'FACT'.'.'.$ext;
  $remote_file = 'ftp' . $file_name;
  $local_file  = APPPATH.'ftp/'.$file_name;
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $local_file);
  endforeach;
```

Pero solo se sube el primero, el archivo temporal se borra al termino de la primera iteración?, o que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que hay en  $lista`? ¿Qué quieres decir con *subir varios archivos a partir de uno solo*?

Comment: En $lista hay un arreglo de ids, y quiero poder multiplicar de un solo archivo, el numero de ids que tiene, por ejemplo, si son 4 ids en $lista, poder multiplicar el archivo subido a 4 y poner en los nombres 'LISTA_ID1', 'LISTA_ID2', etc..

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` mueve el archivo subido desde la carpeta temporal al nuevo destino que le diste en la 1ª iteracción del bucle. Por lo tanto, lo que debes es guardar una referencia de ese archivo y del 1er valor de lista, para crear los otros archivos a partir de ahí.

Answer (score -1):

Pude resolverlo a como lo necesito, solo cambie move_uploaded_file, a copy, quedando así:

```
foreach($_POST['listas'] as $lista):
  $ext         = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  $file_name   = 'EOC_'.$lista.'_'.'FACT'.'.'.$ext;
  $remote_file = 'ftp' . $file_name;
  $local_file  = APPPATH.'ftp/'.$file_name;
  copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $local_file);
  endforeach;
```

Comment: Ten cuidado porque el uso de `copy` es menos seguro que `move_uploaded_file`. Revisa la documentación de ambos, con el uso de `copy` hay menos controles sobre el archivo y el código puede ser usado para meter archivos no deseados en el entorno del servidor.

Comment: Ok, eso no lo sabía, lo tomaré en cuenta, gracias.

Comment: Puedes ver  [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924094/5587982) que explica con sencillez la diferencia entre ambos. Recomiendo que consultes el Manual de PHP y las notas de contribución antes de usar ciertas funciones sensibles, como esta que tiene la potencialidad de subir archivos a tu servidor, lo cual no es una banalidad. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

```php
function subir_lista_archivos(array $file,array $lista_ids): bool {
  /* checkeamos que no hubo errores en la subida del archivo */
  if( $file['error'] > 0 || 0 === $file['size']  ) {
     return false;
  }

  /* Checkeamos que el archivo que se está tratando se subió por un usuario */
  if(!is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name']) ) {
     return false;
  }

  /* Asegura la lista */
  $lista_ids = array_map('intval', $lista_ids);
  if(empty($lista_ids) ) {
    return false;
  }

  $ext         = strtolower(pathinfo(file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

   //Aseguramos la extension
   $ext = mb_ereg_replace("([^\w])", '', $ext);
   if(empty($ext) ) {
     return false;
   }

   $target_dir = APPPATH.'/ftp/';

   //checkeamos permisos
   if(!is_writable($target_dir) ) {
     return false;
   }

  //ya sin peligros copiamos los archivos uno a uno
  foreach($lista_ids as $file_id) {
        $target_file   = $target_dir."EOC_{$file_id}_FACT.{$ext}";
        copy($file['tmp_name'], $target_file);
  }

  return true;
}


subir_lista_archivos($_FILES['file'], $_POST['listas']);
```

Comment: Usar `copy` para subir archivos no es seguro. Por favor, lee la documentación sobre `copy` y sobre `move_uploaded_file`. Ver también [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924094/5587982). El voto negativo es mío, por enseñar código basado en funciones no seguras. Si lo mejoras usando `move_uploaded_file` me avisas. Saludos.

Comment: Copy por sí solo no es tan seguro como `move_uploaded_file`, tienes razón. Sin embargo, la "seguridad" extra que añade `move_uploaded_file` es que antes de mover un archivo hace un `is_uploaded_file` sobre este. Si te fijas en el código,  pongo un  `is_uploaded_file` explícitamente. Eso lo hace tan seguro como  `move_uploaded_file`. Te recomiendo leer la página de php.net sobre subida de archivos para más información

Comment: Por tanto,  en mi opinión, tu comenario no tiene razón de ser sobre mi código y el negativo a mi código es inmerecido y seria recomendable que anularas dicha negativo.